# Proper way to add a user account via bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, users, adduser

Here's the script code I'm using now:

```
getent group $MYGROUP
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    sudo su -c "groupadd $MYGROUP"
fi
sudo su -c "useradd mynewuser -p mypassword -m -g $PRIMARYGRP -G $MYGROUP"
```

This approach works well on openSuse. But there are several problems with the user account it creates on **Ubuntu** so I am seeking help here.

- the terminal prompt isn't set (`echo $PS1` returns nothing)
- the arrow keys and tab key do not work correctly in the terminal
- the password doesn't seem to work (although I'm still unclear exactly what this issue is)
- the /etc/sudoers rights set for this new user are not honored

If instead I manually create the user with `adduser` (instead of useradd) I don't have these problems on Ubuntu. But I can't use `adduser` on openSuse (afaik). Therefore, I need a non-Debian-exclusive script or method of adding user accounts via my bash script that works on Ubuntu (and doesn't stop working on other distros).

Finally, I would like to understand [the differences](https://serverfault.com/a/219009/68517) between `adduser` and `useradd`. For example, I want to know which skeleton directory is used by `adduser` as that might be the reason `useradd` isn't working as expected (because I just accepted the default).

Thanks

Comment: As for the difference: from the useradd man page (`man useradd`): useradd is a low level utility for adding users. On Debian, administrators should usually use adduser(8) instead.

Comment: Also, `sudo su -c "cmd arg1 arg2"` is equivalent to `sudo cmd arg1 arg2`.

Comment: @enzotib thanks. Good to know those are equivalent on Ubuntu because they are not on openSuse. Therefore, I will keep using `sudo su -c "cmd arg1 arg2"` so that it works everywhere I need it to work.

Comment: `adduser` is a *perl* script more than 1000 lines long, so for the differences you can take a look at the script.

Comment: @enzotib Yes, I've been reading `adduser` but I don't know perl. So that's not a good approach for me.

Comment: Let me doubt that `sudo` and `su` work differently on *OpenSUSE* from their standard.

Comment: @enzotib - please educate me then. I'm slightly confused on this issue.

Comment: Now that you've clarified that you're only trying to fix an issue on Ubuntu, the question is on-topic (but marginal). However, [you should not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). [Your U&L question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82923/proper-way-to-add-a-user-account-via-bash-script) has been answered, so I'm voting to close here.

Comment: How do I close it myself?

Comment: Have you considered using [newusers](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/newusers.8.html)?

Comment: @geirha, yes, `newusers` would be an option, but this is working for me: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82923/proper-way-to-add-a-user-account-via-bash-script

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My solution was provided here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82923/proper-way-to-add-a-user-account-via-bash-script
by [Ulrich Schwarz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3929/ulrich-schwarz) and [Joseph R.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/26909/joseph-r). The main thing I had to do was add `-s /bin/bash` to my existing `useradd` command and remove `-p password` which expects an encrypted password.

```
sudo su -c "useradd mynewuser -s /bin/bash -m -g $PRIMARYGRP -G $MYGROUP"
```

Then do this:

```
sudo chpasswd << 'END'
mynewuser:password
END
```

Comment: `echo mynewuser:password | sudo chpasswd` works too.

Answer (score 15):

This will work.

```
sudo adduser myuser --gecos "First Last,RoomNumber,WorkPhone,HomePhone" --disabled-password
echo "myuser:password" | sudo chpasswd
```

Answer (score 2):

my script which automatically constructs a service account with ssh key login and no password

```
#add service group/user
addgroup service-runner
useradd devops-service --create-home --shell /bin/bash --groups service-runner
#gpasswd -a devops-service sudo #allowing sudo requires password, and not a good idea for a service account.
mkdir /home/devops-service/.ssh
chmod 700 /home/devops-service/.ssh
cat devops-service@v2-20150312.pub >> /home/devops-service/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown devops-service:devops-service /home/devops-service -R
```

Comment: fyi, after using my script, I see that "sudo" is pretty much useless with the service account, as no password means it can not use sudo.   You can configure it to allow no-password sudo via visudo but I don't know how to automate that in a script.  Also, probably a service account with no-password sudo isn't a good (security) idea.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can simply use a condition in your script, something like

```
if grep -q 'Ubuntu\|Debian' /etc/issue; then
    adduser .....
else
    useradd .....
fi
```

(cannot verify if the file `/etc/issue` is present on OpenSUSE, otherwise you can put the condition on the existence of such a file).

Comment: Why not simply test the existence of `adduser` with `if command -v adduser >/dev/null; then` or the likes? That's the only thing that matters and not the underlying distributions. Also, there are other distributions besides Debian/Ubuntu and OpenSUSE.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one-liner using [here-strings](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) may help someone:

`adduser someuser --disabled-password <<< ""`