# Kiosk with Chrome on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kiosk

How can I setup 16.04 as a Chrome-based "kiosk"? I.e.:

- `chrome --kiosk` as the only app visible to user,
- user can only click on what's showed by Chrome (no Settings, Unity or other apps or other URLs),
- ideally user has maximally limited privileges,
- user has "autologin" (no password required) enabled,
- admin/superuser can login with some magical key combination or something (e.g. Ctrl-Alt-F1 + login + password) and switch to "full friendly desktop".

Basic googling and other AskUbuntu answers lead me only to some old guides, [~14.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/490826/111779) or [older](https://askubuntu.com/q/124759/111779), which I have trouble applying in 16.04 because of many differences between the distributions (systemd vs. old init, also big changes in GUIs, esp. for system settings).

*edit:* Ideally, I'd prefer a console/script-based guide, so that I could automate it over many computers. But a GUI-based guide would be still better than nothing.

Comment: It's about time for an updated answer about making a Chrome kiosk in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Below is what I managed to build in the end, stitching together various scraps and hints I could find plus some "original research" of my own. I consider it very rough and downright ugly in places, but I need some solution, and it seems to work for now. Fingers crossed...

[image: Warning:]   **PLEASE NOTE you should also consider hardening your Linux for security**,
which is ***absolutely not covered*** by the presented script!

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "USAGE: mkkiosk.sh"
    echo "Create new user 'kiosk' and configure LightDM to auto-login this user to a X session running only Chrome"
    echo "in --kiosk mode."
    exit 1
fi

set -x; set -e
date

# Try to make current user (admin/...) prefer 'ubuntu' to 'kiosk' for session type.
# TODO: currently doesn't seem to work, lightdm still suggests 'kiosk' session and requires manual clicking to change.
cat > ~/.dmrc << EOF
[Desktop]
Session=ubuntu
EOF

# Auto-create user 'kiosk'.
# http://askubuntu.com/a/321943/111779
# NOTE: auto-login is enabled later (autologin-user)
getent group kiosk || (
    sudo su -c "groupadd kiosk"
    sudo su -c "useradd kiosk -s /bin/bash -m -g kiosk"
)

# Install Chrome
# http://askubuntu.com/a/510186/111779
# TODO: somehow pin Chrome version? reportedly, cmdline flags are
# unofficial and can change; OTOH, security updates... though in kiosk, we show
# only one webpage; but admin user also may use Chrome.
grep chrome /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list >&/dev/null || (
    wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
        sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        google-chrome-stable
)

# https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_manager#Session_configuration
#
# - For Chrome flags, see:
#   - http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
#     (via http://askubuntu.com/a/423632/111779)
# - TryExec:
#   not sure what it does, but apparently must be just binary name if present.
#   (see: https://www.virtualbox.org/svn/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Additions/linux/lightdm-greeter/liblightdm-gobject-1.5.0/session.c)
#   TODO: test if we can remove TryExec
# - IMPORTANT NOTE: If below settings are invalid, the session may just
#   silently disappear as a choice in LightDM. You can then try to confirm this
#   by looking in /var/log/lightdm/seat0-greeter.log for message "Ignoring
#   sesion kiosk".
sudo bash -c 'cat > /usr/share/xsessions/kiosk.desktop' << EOF
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Kiosk
Comment=Start a Chrome-based kiosk session
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome --kiosk --window-size=1281,1025 --window-position=0,0 --no-first-run --incognito --no-default-browser-check --disable-translate http://stackoverflow.com
TryExec=/usr/bin/google-chrome
Icon=google-chrome
EOF
sudo -u kiosk bash -c 'cat > ~kiosk/.dmrc' << EOF
[Desktop]
Session=kiosk
EOF
# See LightDM "help" in: /usr/share/doc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.gz
sudo bash -c 'cat > /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/99-kiosk.conf' << EOF
[Seat:*]
user-session=kiosk
EOF
# Setting below options in only 99-kiosk.conf doesn't seem enough (conflicts on autologin-user).
sudo bash -c 'cat > /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf' << EOF
[Seat:*]
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=kiosk
autologin-user-timeout=0
EOF

echo "Done."
```

To get back to "normal user", press <kbd>Alt-F4</kbd> to close Chrome; LightDM will show, where you can login to your "normal" admin/root/... (super-)user. To get back to "kiosk", run:

```
sudo killall lightdm
```

**TODO:** didn't disable screensaver yet (or did it?).
Also, no warranty, it may shoot off your leg, eat your homework, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1) **Chrome in Kiosk** Define a cronjob to launch chrome as kiosk mode and launches everytime system starts. e.g.
//File: chrome

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
@reboot [USER] google-chrome --kiosk --incognito [URL]
```

Copy this file to /etc/cron.d/

Alternatively, you can create a launcher(a .desktop file) with command

```
google-chrome --kiosk --incognito [URL]
```

and copy this to

/home/[USER]/.config/autostart

This enables autostart of chrome browser only for this user.

2) **AutoLogin** Open this file:

```
sudo vi /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
```

Create if does not exist.

Then add these lines to this file.

```
[Seat:*]
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
autologin-user=[USER]
```

Save this file and restart. This enables the user to auto login. This user has of course, limited privileges.

3) **Superuser Login** Use CTRL+ALT+T, this opens terminal

```
gnome-session-quit --logout --force
```

Then login as superuser.

Comment: Steps 2) and 3) currently seem to do nothing? can they be removed? or do you want to rephrase them? Also, I don't understand step 5) (how to switch the user); also, on what base you claim "This user has of course limited privileges"? As of now, your answer is phrased in hard to understand way.

Comment: what you mean by step 2 is definition of chrome kiosk mode(which displays only browser and nothing else).  And step 3 , you, as a super user, can define the privileges for the default user(which can auto-login).  May be I am not clear what you actually want to implement.