# Ubuntu 20.04 (Gnome) create user without graphical interface

Tags: gui, 20.04, adduser, user-profile

I'm trying to create user who is hidden. I would don`t see this user on GUI welcome screen.

I need that user only to administrate some applications.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper way to add a user account via bash script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319714/proper-way-to-add-a-user-account-via-bash-script)

Comment: no this script only adds regular user by "adduser" nothing else

Comment: If you are using GDM3: https://askubuntu.com/a/545764

Comment: @int_ua thanks, you have showed me the way. All to do is just add system user with UID below 1000. 
exmple command: adduser --system userName

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide users from the GDM login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2471/how-to-hide-users-from-the-gdm-login-screen)

Answer (score 0):

to have user without GUI we need "system user".

to do that we can execute:
sudo adduser --system user_name

after that we need to set password:
sudo passwd user_name

Comment: Please do not use "without GUI", it's quite incorrect. What you want is something like "user that is hidden from display manager selection" or "not shown on login screen". Please fix the question title.